# How do I get Anaconda to stop overriding my venv?

Tags: python, anaconda, python-venv

I'm using venv in fish shell. I have anaconda installed from when I used to do data science, but I'd like to switch to venv. I ran `virtualenv venv --python=python3.12` to make the environment. I activated the venv using `source .venv/bin/activate.fish`. But `which python` shows "/home/me/local/anacaonda3/bin/python" and `python --version` returns Python 3.11.5.

If venv was working, I would expect `which python` to path to the "/home/me/goat-book/.venv/bin/python" and for it be Python 3.12.1.

I also have vf installed, but I don't use it.

How do I fix this? I'd prefer to leave anaconda installed in case I want to go back to data science.